Which compression modes of convert of imagemagick are lossless (with -quality 100)?
On my Debian 12,
$ convert -list compress
B44A
B44
BZip
DXT1
DXT3
DXT5
Fax
Group4
JBIG1
JBIG2
JPEG2000
JPEG
LosslessJPEG
Lossless
LZMA
LZW
None
Piz
Pxr24
RLE
RunlengthEncoded
WebP
ZipS
Zip
Zstd

Which compression types are always lossless, and which ones are lossless with the highest setting -quality 100? I failed to find any meaningful summary of all of these these types in one human-readable piece of documentation.

A useful place to start: Wikipedia/Lossless_compression
As a general rule, any compression method that is meant to work on non-image data like binary files or text, will be lossless by definition. For images, as you say, some are either-or like JPEG vs PNG, but others support both.

B44 Wikipedia/OpenEXR

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: No


B44A (see OpenEXR link)

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: No


BZip

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes


DXT1 Wikipedia/S3_Texture_Compression

Applicable File Types: Texture
Lossless: No


DXT3 (see S3_Texture_Compression link)

Applicable File Types: Texture
Lossless: No


DXT5 (see S3_Texture_Compression link)

Applicable File Types: Texture
Lossless: No


Fax Wikipedia/Group_4_compression

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: I assume no since Group4 is meant to supersede it?


Group4 (see Group_4_compression link)

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes


JBIG1 Wikipedia/JBIG

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes


JBIG2 (see JBIG link)

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes (with right settings)


JPEG2000 Wikipedia/JPEG_2000

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes (with right settings)


JPEG

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: No


LosslessJPEG

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes (obviously)


Lossless

Applicable File Types: Various
Lossless: Yes (obviously)


LZMA Wikipedia/LZ77_and_LZ78

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes


LZW (see LZMA link)

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes


None

Applicable File Types: Various
Lossless: Yes (obviously)


Piz (see OpenEXR link)

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes


Pxr24 (see OpenEXR link)

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes (with right settings)


RLE

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes


RunlengthEncoded

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes


WebP Google WebP reference

Applicable File Types: Image
Lossless: Yes (with right settings)


ZipS

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes


Zip

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes


Zstd

Applicable File Types: Binary
Lossless: Yes



